# PostgreSQL complex ordering

Tags: sql, postgresql

Recently I run into the following requirement, and I'm not sure what would be the best solution here.

I have a table having drivers names, let's say A, B; in another table I have some events for these drivers, each event having an issue date, for instance for driver A I have 2017-06-06 and 2017-06-09, while for driver B I have 2017-06-07 and 2017-06-10 (yyyy-mm-dd format).

I need an ordering on this, such that in case I want an ASC order, it compares the earliest issue date for both drivers, and when it finds 2017-06-06 for driver A, it brings after it all the events for that particular driver, and only after that comes the events for driver B, so basically I'd had the following order:

- A - 2017-06-06
- A - 2017-06-09
- B - 2017-06-07
- B - 2017-06-10

I'm not sure how what would be the best solution here...maybe a SELECT in another SELECT, with different ORDER BYs?

Table 1: 
Id name 
1 A
2 B

Table 2: 
issue_date | driver_id
2017-06-06 | 1
2017-06-09 | 1
2017-06-07 | 2
2017-06-10 | 2

Desired output as stated above, that is first compare the issue dates; when found the earliest, bring every other event which has the same driver_id, and only after that go to the next driver's events.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data (for *both* tables) and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can order the second table using window functions:

```
select e.*
from events e
order by min(e.event_date) over (partition by e.driver),
         e.driver, e.event_date;
```

This doesn't join in the second table, but that is a minor modification to the query.

Comment: Thank you! Looks what I want. And in case I want to have the reverse order, that is to take the driver with the latest issue_date, and go DESC?
I tried with max(e.event_date), and/or to put DESC at the order by, but I didn't get the desired output...

Comment: @amnine . . . You probably want `max()` along with `desc`.  However, your description in the comment directly contradicts the question.

Comment: This is what I tried:
select e.*
from events e
order by max(e.event_date) over (partition by e.driver),
         e.driver, e.event_date DESC;

Comment: The desired output being:
B:2017-06-10; B:2017-06-07; A:2017-06-09; A:2017-06-06

Comment: Nevermind, I realized that I've put the DESC at the wrong place. This is what works for me:
`select e.* 
from events e 
order by max(e.event_date) over (partition by e.driver) DESC, 
e.driver, e.event_date DESC;`